# Combining validation in jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am having two select box Month,Year (for expire date).I want to validate both box Combinedly.I need both fields required but one message Like "Please select your Expire date".

In http://bassistance.de/ jquery validation plugin

```
jQuery("#payment_frm").validate({

rules: {
        exp_month:{
            required: true
            },
        exp_year:{
            required: true
            }                       
    },
    messages: {
        exp_month: "Please select expire month",
        exp_year: "Please select expire year"
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: paste you code..what you have done so dar??

Comment: so what error u are getting??? its fine

Comment: There is no error... I want to validate both fields combinly... I mean i am getting two septate messages for exp_month and exp_year . I need to get combine them as  "Please select your Expire date"

Comment: you have to develop custom method ...must read this 'http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validate-tricky-multiple-field-validation-problem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is the 'groups' option - see below - and a grouped error placement.  Not quite sure about the 'messages' bit, haven't tried to tie custom errors back to a group yet.  If it doesn't work, just set both messages the same and call it good.

```
jQuery("#payment_frm").validate({
  groups: {
    expires: "exp_month exp_year"
  },
rules: {
        exp_month:{
            required: true
            },
        exp_year:{
            required: true
            }                       
    },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     if (element.attr("name") == "exp_month" 
                 || element.attr("name") == "exp_year" )
       error.insertAfter("#exp_year");
     else
       error.insertAfter(element);
   },
    messages: {
        expires: 'Please select your expiration date'
    }
});
```

Comment: it groups it but i am only getting message "this field required !" .. How can i change it any idea

Comment: Set 'messages' to the same for both fields then - like you have it in your original example.  See http://jsfiddle.net/qHnMr/ for an example.